# SDWebImageSwiftUI - How to load a fallback image if the first one fails?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui, sdwebimage

I need to grab another image in case the initial one fails and Im having a hard time figuring how to do this with SDWebImageSwiftUI.

Any clue as to how to do this?

Comment: Where is SwiftUI here?

Comment: Its literally a SwiftUI exclusive library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `onFailure` property on `WebImage`. Something like this could work:

```
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct DoubleImageView: View {
    @State var url = URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg")

    var body: some View {
        WebImage(url: url)
            .placeholder(Image(systemName: "person").resizable())
            .onFailure { _ in
                url = URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/72x72.jpg")
            }
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Just change the initial url to `"https://via.placeholder.com"` and that will cause a failure to load the image, which will in turn update the `url` and cause the image to be reloaded with the new `url`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: It’s already it’s own `View` so you can just use that instead of `WebImage` just pass the two urls in the initialiser and what other properties you want to add. I am not sure if you can create it as a `ViewModifier` as it requires `@State`, same goes for an extension. Alternatively you could use [ImageManager](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI#use-imagemanager-for-your-own-view-type) and roll your own solution but that will be much more complicated, or you could use `UIViewRepresentable` to wrap `UIImageView` but that again seem like it would be more complicated

Comment: You are completely right, it already is a reusable view. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you unmarked it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Absolutely not. I think I wanted to upvote your answer in addition to marking it as the accepted answer and accidentally clicked the "check" button, unmarking your answer as accepted. My apologies! Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SDWebImageSwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
             WebImage.init(url: URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png/fff"))
.placeholder(Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder")))
        }
 }
```

The above code worked for me,
Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: 1) As far as I know,  the view in .placeholder is meant to be shown while the image is downloading from the server, not when an error ocurrs. 2) I need to grab the fallback image from the server as well, not a local UIImage as shown on your example.